# Adding an OR condition in Findall, Lxml

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, lxml, findall

I have the following findall expression :

```
for r in p.findall('.//r'):
                 for a in r.findall('.//br'):
                    text+= " "
                 for c in r.findall('.//tab'):
                     text+= " "
```

And i want to add a space in the text variable if i come across the tag `"br"` or `"tab"` , but I want to use a single expression rather than 2 separate ones. something like:

```
for a in r.findall('.//br'|'.//tab'):
```

but this returns an unsupported operand type error.

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'str' and 'str'
```

What is the right syntax for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is using `|` operator for two string operands.

```
>>> 'a' | 'b'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'str' and 'str'
```

Specify `|` inside the string literal. And use [`xpath` method](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._Element-class.html#xpath):

```
for a in r.xpath('.//br|.//tab'):
```

---

If you want to use `findall`, concatenate two list into one and iterate it:

```
for a in r.findall('.//br') + r.findall('.//table'):
```

or using [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
import itertools

for a in itertools.chain(r.findall('.//br'), r.findall('.//table')):
```

Comment: is it possible using findall??

Comment: @Swordy, `findall` does not support full XPath expression. You can combine `findall` with python `if` statement, but it is more verbose.

Comment: @Swordy, How about this? `for a in r.findall('.//br') + r.findall('.//table'): ...`

Comment: awesome , this one works..!! Is this equivalent to my expression in terms of computation time or is it faster??

Comment: @Swordy, I'm not sure. How about `timeit` them yourself.

Comment: yeah , I'll do that.. Would you mind adding the findall method in your answer so that I can accept it..??

Comment: Actually I had the w namespace in it, so it dint work by direct concatenation and before I could try specifying the namespace argument in xpath , you answered with the findall expression..

Comment: This link has a nice tutorial on xml , I understood the logic after  reading from here , finally!! http://www.diveintopython3.net/xml.html

Comment: @Swordy, As I commented before `findall`'s support for xpath is limited. The tutorial you mentioned also address it.

Comment: yeah... Right now I'm just making it work ,from next week onwards ,I'll replace all findall instances by xpath. and btw , the time between ur method and mine is the same..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64568/discussion-between-swordy-and-falsetru).